# dl 380 g9 health led

Tags: hp-proliant, health

This morning our HP Proliant DL380 G9 server welcomed us with a beautiful led blinking. It's the so called "health led". It is flashing a 1Hz frequency and, reading HP docs, I discovered that it means that iLO is rebooting.
Well, this is the first time that I noticed this behavior in two years that we have this server on our premises. The first time that iLO reboots without any my intervention and without a full reboot of the server.
Beside this matter, server seems to work normally.
Why is iLO rebooting?
Thank you for your time. Regards,
Riccardo

Comment: is iLO configured for access? Can you access the server this way? Have you checked the HP Management software to ensure it's not another reason for this light to be flashing?

Comment: What colour is it flashing?  Can you access iLO?  Is it still flashing?  May be worth phoning HP support?

Comment: Dunno - log into iLO and look at the logs

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for your answers.
Answering to BlueComputer, health led was flashing green.
And answering to Dave and Chopper3, I had been able to normally login to iLO. No problem there.
The problem was the health of another component, the RAID controller in this case which I discovered seeking into the system routines at boot time. The led was signalling a degraded state of a logical disk because of the failure of one phisycal disk. Once I substituted the disk, the led stopped flashing and showed itself solid green again.
Best regards.

Comment: You didn't see the disk status light flashing?